# Odd-one-out puzzles

Tags: word, odd-one-out

I am compiling a list of word puzzles, one for each letter in the alphabet.
Three words are given (two starting with the same letter), and the goal is to find something in common for every pair of words.
Bonus if the three words have nothing obvious in common.

Example A:
**Apple, Airplane, Bird**

- Apple and airplane starts with 'A'.
- Apples and birds are found in trees.
- Airplanes and birds can fly.

Example B: **Ball, Banana, Orange**

- Ball and banana starts with 'B'.
- The ball and the orange are round.
- The banana and the orange are fruits.

Example C:
**Chicken, Chair, Horse**

- Chicken and chair starts with 'C'.
- Chicken and horse are animals.
- The horse and the chair have four legs.

Example W: **Window, Wig, Glasses**

- Window and wig starts with 'W'.
- Wig and glasses are things you wear.
- You can see through window and glasses.

Example X: **X-ray, xylophone, pulse**

- x-ray and xylophone start with 'X'.
- X-ray and pulse might be checked at the doctors.
- Xylophone and pulse are musical terms.

Example Z: **Zeppelin, Zebra, Seagull**

- Zeppelin and zebra start with 'Z'.
- Zebra and seagull are animals.
- Zeppelin and seagulls fly.

The words involved should be relatively simple, I want to make a childrens-style book for my kid.

I am missing a bunch of letters, and the ones I have are not that nice.

Comment: [tag:odd-one-out]

Comment: Do the 2 somethings in common need to be unique for each letter (meaning 52 rules in total)?

Comment: @MikeQ: Not really, but it is more fun if there is some variation.

Comment: just an idea substitute cherry for orange , dog for horse, and albatross for seagull and you have an n,n,n+1 pattern.  although X,X,Y could be challenging

Comment: Isn't this just a puzzle-creation question?

Comment: @ev3commander: Sure.

Answer (score 5):

Example Y: 
Yellow, yogurt, orange

Yellow and yogurt start with Y.
Yellow and orange are colors.
Orange and yogurt are food.

Comment: That is nice! I guess 'orange' instead of 'peach' makes it even clearer, since orange is a more used edible/color.

Comment: I chose peach because example B has orange. I can change it to orange..

Answer (score 3):

Example H: **HC Andersen, Duckling, Hen**

- A duckling and a hen are both birds.
- HC Andersen wrote *The Ugly Duckling*
- Hen and HC Andersen both start with 'H'

Comment: That is a nice example - although the relation I had in mind are 'both X and Y are ...'

Answer (score 2):

Example T: **Elephant, Tree, Tiger**

- Tree and Tiger both start with T
- Elephant and Tiger are animals
- Elephant and Tree have trunk(s)

Answer (score 1):

Example M: Mangos,Madagascar Cuckoo,Parrot

Mangos and Madagascar Cuckoo both starts with 'M'.

Madagascar Cuckoo and Parrot both are birds.

Parrot eat Mangos.

Comment: what classification excludes Degree?

Comment: perhaps you don't understand "excludes"

Comment: This is not really in the spirit I am looking for - the relation between objects should be reflexive, i.e., "both X and Y are ..." or "X and Y have ..." while excluding Z.

Answer (score 1):

Example K: **Knock, Kiss, Ring**

- Knock and Kiss both start with K
- One can give a Kiss or a Ring to someone they love
- A Knock or a Ring can be heard when someone is at your door

Another I like:
**Kid, King, and Lamb**

- Kid and King both start with K
- Kid and Lamb are names for young animals
- Lamb and King are both imagery for Jesus Christ